# Codeplex/Sourceforge for internal use

Tags: open-source, project-management, version-control, codeplex

I'm looking for a free/open source collaborative project manager that can be deployed internally in my workplace that would act similar to Codeplex or Sourceforge. Does anyone know of something like this, and if so do you have experience with it.

**Requirements:**

- Open Source *or* Free
- Locally Deployable
- Has the same types of features found in Sourceforge / Codeplex

  - Issue/Feature Tracking
  - Community Interaction (ie. Voting, Roles, etc.)
  - SCM Integration *(Optional)*
- .NET/Windows Friendly *(Optional)*

Every business ends up having internal utilities, and domain specific apps that developers create to make life easier. Given the input of the internal developer community they have the potential to become much better (can you say [GMail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Gmail#Internal_development)...), and I would simply like to foster such an environment internally by providing an easy place for that interaction to take place.

**UPDATE:**

So I like what I am seeing in both Trac and GForge, but both are heavily geared towards UNIX/Subversion environments. I should have specified this, but we are a MS shop from top to bottom. How practical do you think it is going to be to try and use these in a MS .NET environment? Would that be like trying to shove a square peg through a round hole?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like redmine for this: http://www.redmine.org.  The only thing it's missing from your criteria is voting, but there might even be a plugin for this.

Trac is also popular (http://trac.edgewall.org) but it lacks suport for aggregation of data across projects.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, but I am going to have to say that Trac best suits my needs. GForge looks nice but has too many requirements for Linux based install.

Comment: Trac rules. You can tune it to fit all your needs. You can even install a automated build system designed for Trac: Bitten (same developer). The only thing I do not like at trac is the wiki syntax. I would prefer to use MediaWiki wiki-syntax instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try [GForge](http://gforge.org/), it's a SourceForge fork and has most of its features.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, but I am going to have to say that Trac best suits my needs. GForge looks nice but has too many requirements for Linux based install.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, Trac should work. IMHO setting up Subversion should be relatively easy on Windows too, there are great Windows clients for it (tortoiseSvn), and Trac runs on python, so it will work on Windows too.

Answer (score 2):

Other advantages of Sourceforge Enterprise are these plugins. There are extra plugins for Visual Studio wich can be found [here](http://desktop-vs.open.collab.net/) and [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/integrations/).

Answer (score 1):

SourceForge Enterprise Edition 4.4 is available for free for up to 15 users.  We use it for our development team and another development team where I work.

It's been working great for us.  It has subversion and cvs built in (whichever you wish to use).  If you plan on accessing it over the internet you might want to enable HTTPS. I had to do a little finagling to get HTTPS to work correctly (finding the right CentOS packages to install).  If you wanted to use this solution with HTTPS I wouldn't mind if you sent me a message asking for help.

It comes with a VM for VMWare Player:
http://www.collab.net/downloads/sfee/index4.4.html

Answer (score 1):

[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/launchpad-project) has support for Code Hosting and version control, Bug tracking, Blueprints, Answers, Polls, Translations, etc.

Launchpad is used by the Ubuntu Project.

A few weeks ago, Launchapad was released as open source.

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the same thing, something like Trac but in .NET,  after a quick GOOGLE search (I have never tried these tools) I found

sharpforge (This no longer looks free!)

I like how the site .netTiers looks.
They use screwturn wiki.
It is totally free if you fulfill all GPLv2 statements.

Answer (score 0):

[Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) and [BeanStalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) are nice, both have things like; wiki, discussion, alerts, chat, ticketing, Trac, Git and Subversion

Comment: Both of these require payment to unlock the really nice feature set, and neither of them are locally deployable.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)? It's pretty simple, but does it's Job for a lot of Open Source projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would concur on the [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) suggestion.  I use it both for an open source project and for an internal project.  It has decent issue tracking and integration with Subversion which allows links between tickets and subversion checkins.  It also has an integrated wiki, which can be of some use for documentation.  Although we do not use it for voting / community type features, I know there's a number of addons to it that might serve this purpose.