# creating an internal opensource type system

Tags: svn, iis, collaboration

so I am looking to create an open source type environment to allow our international partners to view and contribute to our code.

currently we use SVN for source control and fogbugz for defect tracking. This manages most of our requirements however. with Fogbugz enabling community discussions and wiki's

- WebSVN doesnt seem to run on IIS
- svn over http dosnt seem to run on IIS.

Can someone correct me if this research is in fact wrong (and where to find the directions to set these systems up)

suggest other tools that will achieve a similar setup.

Comment: Asked the same question a while back: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83269/codeplex-sourceforge-for-internal-use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83269/codeplex-sourceforge-for-internal-use)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP access to Subversion runs over Apache.  You can run both IIS and Apache on a windows server, you just have to set one of them to use a different port like 81 or 8080.

Chapter 6 of [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is all about configuring your server to run Subversion.

I have not used it, but others have recommended a [One-Click Setup](http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/) tool that will install and configure subversion on your server.  My guess is that after using this tool you would still have to adjust your port settings in either Apache or IIS.

Comment: It is possible to server pages over port 80 with IIS and Apache on the same server if you use mode_rewrite to redirect IIS traffic from Apache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108387/apache-and-iis-side-by-side-both-listening-to-port-80-on-windows2003/108423#108423

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SVN-IIS](http://www.svniis.org/) yet?

Comment: Neat idea, but you still need to have Subversion installed on a running Apache installation.